# What is the problem on this code, for running EMD in R studio?

Tags: r

```
library(EMD) ### Empirical Mode Decomposition 
ndata <- 3000 
tt2 <- seq(0, 9, length=ndata) 
xt2 <- sin(pi * tt2) + sin(2* pi * tt2) + sin(6 * pi * tt2) + 0.5 * tt2 
try <- emd(xt2, tt2, boundary="wave")
```

> Error in emd(xt2, tt2, boundary = "wave") :unused argument (boundary = "wave")

Comment: It say this argument is not set up in the function `emd`. Is it a custom function or is it in a package (I don't know it, and I could help you easily if I know from where you use it ^^ )

Comment: library(EMD)
### Empirical Mode Decomposition
ndata <- 3000
tt2 <- seq(0, 9, length=ndata)
xt2 <- sin(pi * tt2) + sin(2* pi * tt2) + sin(6 * pi * tt2)  + 0.5 * tt2

try <- emd(xt2, tt2, boundary="wave")

Comment: Hello, thanks for adding this code, but next time, edit your question, as I dit it ;)

Comment: I runned the code and it work without returning the error you provided. Maybe check in your environment if you have another function called emd, or if your package is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the session the problem was solved!!!!!!!